# Vim buffer breadcrumbs plugin

Tags: vim

Are there any plugins in Vim that allow you to move through the list of buffers you have had open in order? `Ctrl-6` does it for two files, but I want something that does more.  For example, if I open buffers a, b, c, d in order, I want to type something to back to c, back to b, forward to c again, etc.

Comment: Just curious of what the differences you want compared to Ctrl-O/Tab (see: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Jumping_to_previously_visited_locations) is this not sufficient enough to go back-and-forth?  Or you need more functionality than Ctrl-O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple plugin that does what I want in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706958/vim-navigating-to-previous-and-next-buffers-in-edit-history)

[vim-bufsurf](https://github.com/ton/vim-bufsurf)

Answer (score 3):

This is available via built-in vim commands: `bprevious` and `bnext`, or `bp` and `bn`.

Using your example, open the files, and type <kbd>:bp</kbd> to go to the buffer with *c*, then <kbd>:bp</kbd> and you're in buffer *b*, and <kbd>:bn</kbd> gets you back to buffer *c*.

Also convenient: type e.g. <kbd>:b1</kbd> to go to buffer 1, if it exists, and `:b myFile.txt` to go to the buffer containing the file name `myFile.txt`.

`bprevious` and `bnext` always follow the ordering of the buffer list. You can observe this ordering with the `:ls` command. Notice that each buffer is assigned an increasing number. `bprevious` and `bnext` will follow this ordering *regardless* of how many windows and/or tabs you're moving between.

e.g. if you've opened *a, b, c, d* as in your example, and you have two split windows, the first with buffer *a* and the second with buffer *b*, a `bnext` in the first window will put you in buffer *b*, and a `bnext` in the second window will put you in buffer *c*.

Comment: bp and bn are just what I needed.  I was making it too hard, rather than just looking for built-in functionality. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, after looking a bit, bp and bn are NOT what I need.  If I have several windows open and move around a bit, bp does NOT bring up buffers I want.  As a matter of fact, it brings up seemingly random ones.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @KyleHeironimus see the edit. vims buffer handling/movement facilities are pretty primitive, not even a most-recently-used facility. Folks that need more use buffer-management plugins like [Ctrl-p](http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/). For others it's enough to just keep track of filenames and buffer numbers.

Comment: ctrl-p is great, but if sometimes I'm just tracking code down the call stack and want to just go back two buffers, for example, without messing with ctrl-p or even remembering what file I was in.