# Quickly switch to the last edited buffer

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there a good command that will switch to the last buffer (and place) where an edit was made? I would prefer not to have to install a plugin just for this (but if there is no other way then I would).

This is not solved by the BufSurf plugin which actually goes back through the navigation history which was the answer to [a question that sounds similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706958/vim-navigating-to-previous-and-next-buffers-in-edit-history).

Answer (score 7):

The previous buffer can be accessed via the *alternate file*: `<C-^>` or `:e #`.

`gi` / `` `^ `` go back to the last edit location *in the current buffer*.

Unfortunately, there's no command that combines both (but I personally have never missed that).

Comment: Thanks for the input, but your answer seems to be: you don't know?

Comment: I'm pretty sure about no built-in commands; I don't know any such plugin (even though I closely follow those). A previous, similar question hasn't yielded anything, neither, so I'm gonna close this now.